# PostgresSQL Cannot order by json_build_object result (got from subquery)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query. And I'd like to order by json field:

```
SELECT "ReviewPacksModel"."id",
        (SELECT json_build_object(
                  'totalIssues', COUNT(*),
                  'openIssues', COUNT(*) filter (where "issues".status = 'Open'),
                  'fixedIssues', COUNT(*) filter (where "issues".status = 'Fixed')
                )
         FROM "development"."issues" "issues"
           JOIN "development"."reviewTasks" as "rt" ON "issues"."reviewTaskId" = "rt".id
         WHERE "issues"."isDeleted" = false
           AND "rt"."reviewPackId" = "ReviewPacksModel"."id"
        ) as "issueStatistic"
FROM "development"."reviewPacks" AS "ReviewPacksModel"
WHERE "ReviewPacksModel"."projectId" = '2'
  AND "ReviewPacksModel"."mode" IN ('Default', 'Live')
  AND "ReviewPacksModel"."status" IN ('Draft', 'Active')
ORDER BY "issueStatistic"->'totalIssues'
LIMIT 50;
```

And I get an error:

```
ERROR: column "issueStatistic" does not exist
```

If I try to order by `issueStatistic` without `->'totalIssues'`, I will get another error:

```
ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

It seems like I cannot extract field from the JSON.

I also tested it with this query:

```
SELECT "ReviewPacksModel".*,
        (SELECT Count(*)
           FROM "development"."issues" "issues"
             JOIN "development"."reviewTasks" as "rt" ON "issues"."reviewTaskId" = "rt".id
           WHERE "issues"."isDeleted" = false
             AND "rt"."reviewPackId" = "ReviewPacksModel"."id"
        ) AS "issueStatistic"
FROM "development"."reviewPacks" AS "ReviewPacksModel"
WHERE "ReviewPacksModel"."projectId" = '2'
  AND "ReviewPacksModel"."mode" IN ('Default', 'Live')
  AND "ReviewPacksModel"."status" IN ('Draft', 'Active')
ORDER BY "issueStatistic"
LIMIT 50;
```

And it works without any problems. But I cannot use it cause it's not possible to return multiple columns from a subquery. I also tried to use alternatives like `array_agg`, `json_agg`, etc. but it doesn't help.

I know that it's possible to make multiple queries, but they aren't super fast and for me it's better to use `json_build_object`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aliases in `ORDER BY`, but you cannot use expressions involving aliases.

You'll have to use a subquery.

Also, you cannot order on a `json`. You'll have to convert it to a sortable data type. In the following I assume it is a number; you'll have to adapt the query if my assumption is wrong.

```
SELECT id, "issueStatistic"
FROM (SELECT "ReviewPacksModel"."id",
             (SELECT json_build_object(
                       'totalIssues', COUNT(*),
                       'openIssues', COUNT(*) filter (where "issues".status = 'Open'),
                       'fixedIssues', COUNT(*) filter (where "issues".status = 'Fixed')
                     )
              FROM "development"."issues" "issues"
                JOIN "development"."reviewTasks" as "rt" ON "issues"."reviewTaskId" = "rt".id
              WHERE "issues"."isDeleted" = false
                AND "rt"."reviewPackId" = "ReviewPacksModel"."id"
             ) as "issueStatistic"
     FROM "development"."reviewPacks" AS "ReviewPacksModel"
     WHERE "ReviewPacksModel"."projectId" = '2'
       AND "ReviewPacksModel"."mode" IN ('Default', 'Live')
       AND "ReviewPacksModel"."status" IN ('Draft', 'Active')
    ) AS subq
ORDER BY CAST ("issueStatistic"->>'totalIssues' AS bigint)
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: @S-Man I didn't think of that. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Your solution works! The root cause is that I cannot use expression result in order by? Is it correct?

Yeah, now I have to find out a way how to compose this query by my ORM, but this is another problem :)

Answer (score 2):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d39dc132aa9fe87834b82842bc74c804)

You cannot order by type `json` because, simply spoken, there is no definition on how to handle different types included in the JSON object. But this gives you a type `json`:

```
"issueStatistic"->'totalIssues'
```

However, type jsonb can be ordered. So, instead of creating a type json object, you should use `jsonb_build_object()` to create a type `jsonb` object.

Alternatively you could cast your expression into type `int` (mind the `->>` operator instead of your `->` which casts the output into type `text` which can be directly cast into type `int`):

```
("issueStatistic"->>'totalIssues')::int
```

**Edit:**

As Laurenz mentioned correctly, to use aliases you need a separate subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM (
    -- <your query minus ORDER clause>
) s
ORDER BY "issueStatistic"->'totalIssues'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help. I still get an error: `ERROR: column "issueStatistic" does not exist`. I changed to `jsonb_build_object()` and used this cast `("issueStatistic"->>'totalIssues')::int`. Any ideas?

Comment: @KirillVarikov Did this help? If any answer helped, don't forget to UPVOTE all of them (that honors the time and effort, the repliers invested into your problem). If one of them solves your problem, please don't forget to ACCEPT additionally (this closes the question).